# How to select <select> elements with no html in them through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-selectors

I have following html select elements

```
    <select  id="options1" title="prd_name" name="options">
       <option value="optiona">Option A</option>
       <option value="optionb">Option B</option>
       <option value="optionc">Option C</option>
    </select>
    <select  id="options2" title="prd_name" name="options"> </select>
    <select  id="options3" title="prd_name" name="options"> </select>
    <select  id="options4" title="prd_name" name="options"> </select>
```

Only the first select element with id="options1" has option tags in it, the rest of select elements are empty. I want to select those empty select elements so that I be able to populate options into them, without touching the first select element which already has options into it. How can I do this especially through Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selector `select:empty`; alternatively you can use `select:not(:has(option))`

```js
console.log($("select:empty"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select id="options1" title="prd_name" name="options">
  <option value="optiona">Option A</option>
  <option value="optionb">Option B</option>
  <option value="optionc">Option C</option>
</select>
<select id="options2" title="prd_name" name="options"></select>
<select id="options3" title="prd_name" name="options"></select>
<select id="options4" title="prd_name" name="options"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 this solution is perfect and works as I need it to. Both forms of the code work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var $select = $("select").filter(function () {
         return !$(this).find("option").length;
       });
console.log($select);
```

$select will give you all the select boxes except the with option elements
then you can loop over $select and perform any task on it

Comment: The select element with "options1" has been dynamically populated with the option tags, it could have been any select element or even it could have been more than one select elements which are populated with option tags. I just want to select those select elements which have not been populated with option tags yet.